# ReentrantLock gets mysteriously unlocked within the same thread, even while no other threads are accessing it

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization, reentrantlock

I have some code that I thought would be very straightforward:

```
public int internalWrite(byte[] data, int offset, int size) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        if (state == State.RELEASED) throw new TrackReleasedException();
        return track.write(data, offset, size, AudioTrack.WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);
    } finally {
        if (!lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
            Log.e("phonographnative", "internalWrite() lock is not held by current thread! " + Thread.currentThread());
        } else lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

The `lock` is a `fair` ReentrantLock, but the issue also occurs with a non-`fair` one. `track` is an Android AudioTrack; its `write` method is mostly native code (but nothing to do with threading). It has no access to the `lock` anyway. The exception is practically never thrown in practice (and never while investigating this behaviour). What happens is that, very reproducibly (more on this later), the lock will mysteriously get unlocked within the same thread, causing the log message to occur. Previously, when I didn't have this check in place, an IllegalMonitorStateException would, expectedly, be thrown. After this happened a couple of times, there would be a `java.lang.AssertionError: Attempt to repark`, within the lock's code itself. Some exemplary log output:

```
2019-03-20 12:20:37.428 8097-8181/com.kabouzeid.gramophone.debug E/phonographnative: internalWrite() lock is not held by current thread! Thread[phonographnative-decoding-65308.0,5,main]
2019-03-20 12:20:37.428 8097-8184/com.kabouzeid.gramophone.debug E/phonographnative: internalWrite() lock is not held by current thread! Thread[phonographnative-decoding-65308.0,5,main]
2019-03-20 12:20:37.428 8097-8181/com.kabouzeid.gramophone.debug E/phonographnative: internalWrite() lock is not held by current thread! Thread[phonographnative-decoding-65308.0,5,main]
2019-03-20 12:20:37.428 8097-8184/com.kabouzeid.gramophone.debug E/phonographnative: internalWrite() lock is not held by current thread! Thread[phonographnative-decoding-65308.0,5,main]
2019-03-20 12:20:37.430 8097-8184/com.kabouzeid.gramophone.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: phonographnative-decoding-65308.0
    Process: com.kabouzeid.gramophone.debug, PID: 8097
    java.lang.AssertionError: Attempt to repark
        at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2143)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:840)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:898)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1220)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:312)
        at com.kabouzeid.gramophone.service.ffmpeg.AudioContext.internalWrite(AudioContext.java:197)
        at com.kabouzeid.gramophone.service.ffmpeg.AudioContext.write(AudioContext.java:177)
        at com.kabouzeid.gramophone.service.ffmpeg.FFmpegPlayer.decodeAndPlayAudio(Native Method)
        at com.kabouzeid.gramophone.service.ffmpeg.FFmpegPlayer.lambda$new$0(FFmpegPlayer.java:72)
        at com.kabouzeid.gramophone.service.ffmpeg.-$$Lambda$FFmpegPlayer$MKAlsDZBJzprKYoChfgA-0JlIi8.run(lambda)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

This happens even if no other threads are trying to run this code, and even if I comment out all other attempts to lock/unlock this lock (by other threads, in different code sections). This problem rarely occurs intermittently, but reliably when I try to *unpause* the AudioTrack that is being written to. It does not happen when initially writing to it, or when doing anything else (like starting playback from scratch). This unpausing happens on an entirely different thread, and I have not been able to determine the causal connection between the two things. It might just be some random scheduler madness.

The `internalWrite` method is called very frequently, on the order of thousands of times per second. I have a feeling that this is just a bug within Android's implementation of `ReentrantLock`, given that the assertion being hit is entirely within JVM code. (What does "Attempt to repark" even mean?) But I can't rule out that I missed some other detail in my own code, and I'd appreciate any thoughts about this!

The full code can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/meew0/Phonograph/blob/cafe13db63de670568b6b94225b8cca21ec80da8/app/src/main/java/com/kabouzeid/gramophone/service/ffmpeg/AudioContext.java#L187). I have also tracked down the relevant sections in Android code: [AudioTrack#write](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/java/android/media/AudioTrack.java#2267), [native_write_byte](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/jni/android_media_AudioTrack.cpp#656) (the method is called differently), [writeToTrack](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/jni/android_media_AudioTrack.cpp#628), [AudioTrack->write](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/refs/heads/master/media/libaudioclient/AudioTrack.cpp#1779). However, they have not helped me at all in elucidating this error.

Comment: Interesting bug. I would suggest trying to learn more about which thread the lock thinks it is owned by - either using the debugger, or by subclassing `ReentrantLock` in order to expose `getOwner()`. Then I'd try to capture the moment the state changes using a conditional breakpoint.

Comment: I did try that at one point, it appears the lock just gets unlocked completely, rather than being owned by a specific thread (`getOwner` returns `null`). I also tried the breakpoint thing but I couldn't set a statement breakpoint within JVM code, and using a method breakpoint degraded performance to a point of complete unusability.

Comment: You should make `lock` private.  If you have a reason for not making it private, then that's probably where the problem is.

Comment: @meew0 Well, if you want to probe the problem even further, you could just copy the source code for ReentrantLock -- call it ReentrantLock2, and use that class instead. You could set breakpoints where you wish, and add custom debugging code. Might even cause a change in behavior.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I see your point, but the problem persists even if I remove *all* other references to the lock, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but why do you call `lockInterruptibly()`? If this function really is called thousands of times per second, then why can't you just call `lock.lock()`?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Occasionally, there are periods where other threads need to do (comparatively) long processing, and the thread executing `internalWrite` needs to wait for that. However, it would still be nice if this thread could be interrupted during those wait periods. You're right though, it's not really that essential for it to lock interruptibly, but regular `lock` doesn't appear to make a difference to my issue...

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code might releasing the Lock / `lock.unlock()` at while calling inside the
`track.write(data, offset, size, AudioTrack.WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);`

when you are trying to release lock / `lock.unlock()` at 2nd time in finally block it does not have any lock with current thread so its throwing an Error as per your code logic.

Please check in your code if you are releasing the Lock / `lock.unlock()` in `track.write(data, offset, size, AudioTrack.WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);`

If you can't remove `lock.unlock()` inside `track.write(data, offset, size, AudioTrack.WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);`

Then you do "DOUBLE LOCK" / Acquire Lock for TWO TIMES then release or unlock for TWO TIMES your problem will be solved...

Sample Code for Better Understanding:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
public class Main
{
    private final static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        System.out.println("Hello World:::::"+internalWrite());
      } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
          ie.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    
    public static int internalWrite() throws InterruptedException{
      lock.lockInterruptibly();
      lock.lockInterruptibly();// Comment this line to reproduce your issue
      try {
         if(lock.isHeldByCurrentThread())
         System.out.println("lock::::"+lock.isHeldByCurrentThread());
         lock.unlock();
         System.out.println("lock::::"+lock.isHeldByCurrentThread());
         return 1;
      } finally {
          if (!lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
            System.out.println("phonographnative internalWrite() lock is not held by current thread! " + Thread.currentThread());
        } else lock.unlock();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are able to remove `lock.unlock()` inside `track.write(data, offset, size, AudioTrack.WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);`

   Then Your Current Code will work Fine, without doing any modification.

(OR)

2. If you are not able to remove `lock.unlock()` inside `track.write(data, offset, size, AudioTrack.WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);`

   Current code need to adapted with **twice an acquire lock**:

   ```
   lock.lockInterruptibly();
   lock.lockInterruptibly();
   ```

```
public int internalWrite(byte[] data, int offset, int size) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        if (state == State.RELEASED) throw new TrackReleasedException();
        return track.write(data, offset, size, AudioTrack.WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);
    } finally {
        if (!lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
            Log.e("phonographnative", "internalWrite() lock is not held by current thread! " + Thread.currentThread());
        } else lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is this:

1. A thread (A) acquires `lock` and starts working.
2. Another thread (B) tries to acquire `lock` and is blocked because A has not yet called `unlock()` on `lock`.
3. B is interrupted by another thread (C). C does not have to know about the variable `lock`.
4. The blocking of B is terminated because it tried to acquire the lock *interruptably*.
5. Thus the `finally`-block is executed by B. B did not acquire `lock` because A had not released it when the interrupt occurred. Thus `lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()` is `false` for B.

Instead of assuming that in the case of `if (!lock.isHeldByCurrentThread())` in the `finally` block would be wrong or an unwanted state for B you can simply go on without logging an error/warning and is also OK not to `unlock()` the `lock` in this case.

```
public int internalWrite(byte[] data, int offset, int size) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        lock.lockInterruptibly(); // if outside the try block the next lines would be executed in the described situation without having acquired the lock
        if (state == State.RELEASED) throw new TrackReleasedException();
        return track.write(data, offset, size, AudioTrack.WRITE_NON_BLOCKING); 
    } finally {
        if (lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```